# Set nosniff header for all the browsers that support it except IE11

Tags: apache, .htaccess, header

In my .htaccess file i have

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Disable content sniffing, since it's an attack vector.
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

which sets the nosniff header for all the browsers that support it.

I want to set the nosniff header for all the browsers that support it except for IE11. I am using Apache/2.2.23 on CentOS.
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of interest can I ask why you want to disable it for IE11 only?

Comment: I have several images that are being dynamically generated using a Drupal module, when the nosniff header is on IE11 can't display those images.

Comment: In that case your Dynamic Generator does not set the correct mimetype, I would set the mimetype instead of making the nosniff header conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't

Long answer: In theory you should be able to use something like the following:

```
BrowserMatch "MSIE 11.0;" allow_sniff
Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff env=!allow_sniff
```

However IE11 deliberately masks it's user-agent pretending to be something else. See this post for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx

So ultimately the above won't work. You should instead fix the reason you need to change the behaviour for IE11 (fix your dupal module, or turn off no sniff for all browsers).

Answer (score 1):

You can enable it by modifying your Apache settings or your .htaccess file, and adding the following line to it:

Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

This article from Microsoft explains it: Reducing MIME type security risks
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622941(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>

Comment: The question is about not setting it for IE11, not about how to set it.